# Best place to call bower from grails

Tags: grails, bower

I use bower to manage my asset dependencies for my grails apps and was wondering where if there is a callback or something that I can hook into to call bower when running `war` or `run-app`. I know how to do the command execution from Groovy, just wondering if someone can recommend a way to automate the integration of bower short of writing a custom plugin or something like that.

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 if that helps.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to hook into the lifecycle events for Grails is through the `_Events.groovy` within your project's `scripts` directory. More about this can be found in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#events). Typically you will see this being used in Plugins, but I seem to recall it works for applications as well (It does, I just tested it).

```
// scripts/_Events.groovy
eventCompileStart = {
 // place your code here.
}
```